# Error 400 when trying to connect Heroku keys

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I'm currently setting up Heroku CLI. When I try to connect my account, I get an error 400.

```
sudo heroku keys:add
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: seanfindlay3@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
 ▸    HTTP Error: https://api.heroku.com/login 400 Bad Request
 ▸    Invalid response from API.
 ▸    HTTP 400
 ▸    {*my email* *my password*}
 ▸    
 ▸    Are you behind a proxy?
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy
```

As far as I know, I'm not behind a proxy. I couldn't find anything on this topic online.

Answer (score 0):

Your CLI is out of date and needs to be updated